# Can anyone remove all the comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, code-of-conduct

In one question I've posted, there were a few comments upon my wrong capitalisation of a scientist's name.

Another user had already edited it, and someone else had negatively voted it (I really wish I could see the real and actual reason for them negatively voting, so that I could improve my questions), so now my title question has a shade lighter than normal questions (is it correct to assume that is how it is for negatively voted questions?).

However, I was completely surprised to see that now my post contains none of the comments that were there till yesterday. Can someone with a higher reputation points delete all the comments in the same way they can edit the posts, or is this a glitch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) (specifically, see the section titled "Who can delete comments?")

Comment: @Ryan thank you for clearing that. But that explains if only some of the comments are gone, but  All of the comments have vanished from mine, and none of it deserved to be flagged too.

Comment: Glad to help! Unfortunately, it's hard to say why a moderator might have deleted them - only they would know.  Likely it got too chatty (comments are not intended for extended discussion) and a moderator decided it was more noise than valuable.  Deleting comments isn't a punitive action: they're designed to be temporary.  If you really want to know, you could ask on that site's meta, and a moderator might answer.

Comment: Also when there are multiple comment flags on a question, and no **really** valuable comments moderators sometimes opt to remove all comments with a single button click. This is easier for them then to handle all individually flagged comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) can delete any comment/comments. The help center states:

> Moderator votes are binding. Any place we have voting — close, open, **delete**, undelete, offensive, migration, etc — that vote will reach the threshold and take effect immediately if a single moderator casts a vote.

(bold mine)

Also, all users above 15 rep can use the [flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) feature to bring moderator attention to comments.

In your case, someone might have flagged the comments as no longer needed after the capitalization issue was fixed in your question. A moderator would then delete all of the no longer needed comments to clear up clutter.

Comment: Also note that if comments are flagged as rude it only needs 6 flags to get a comment removed, no mods will be involved. If a comment contains certain trigger words comment flags lead to immediate removal.